# Is checkbox checked (inside each() loop)?

Tags: jquery

I'm looping through multiple checkboxes with the same class with function each() and inside the loop I need to be able to tell whether the checkbox is checked or not. How to do that?

```
$('.checkbox').each(function() {
    var is_checked = 'no';
    // I need to change the value of the is_checked variable to 'yes'
    // if the checkbox is checked
    //
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
var is_checked = this.checked ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Answer (score 4):

One way is:

```
$('#yourcheckbox').is(':checked');
```

Comment: That's true, but it's harder to read and slower than just saying `this.checked`. You don't have to use jQuery syntax for everything you do, the DOM does still exist.

Comment: Absolutely, I was trying to keep it within the jquery code he already has, but you're right this.checked is probably faster, and more simple.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the `:checkbox:checked` selector instead?  That way you get the list of all the checkboxes that are checked and iterate over those.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input:checkbox[class='.checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
 // this will only loop thru checked boxes (checked = true)
}
```

OR

```
$('.checkbox').each(function() {    
 // or return a boolean for each one
 var is_checked = $(this).is(":checked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get all the unchecked boxes

```
$("input:not(:checked)")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `$(this).val()` will give you "true" if checked and then `$(this).val("true")` will set the value